# $1/$2 Live - Bottom set on flop and facing 3bet

Tags: live, hand-history, nl200, casino

I play weekly at my casino and at `$1/$2` they have buy-in of `$60 min-$200 max`. This is one of my hand I played last week and I am interested in seeing how you would play this hand when you have a top set on the flop and facing `3-bet` on a straight-board.

The villain in this hand is a a hyper-aggressive player who is down 600 (3 buy-ins) and playing with his 4th buy-in. But, after his first two buy-ins he is playing little tight and aggressive when he plays.

$1/$2 Full Ring - Holdem - 9 players  (currently 6 seated)

**Villain (middle) - $420**
**Hero (BB) - $460**

Hero has 7⋄7♣

Villain calls from middle - folds back to SB who raises to 10. Hero calls from BB and villain calls.

Flop comes : J♣7♥8♠

**SB checks, Hero checks, Villain bets 15, SB calls.**

Villain has be known to be aggressive and takes control of pot from flop.

**Hero raises to 45.**

**Villain re-raises (3bets) to 145. SB folds.**

What should Hero do?

I will post the results after checking your reviews. But, from what I saw this villain does not raise too much over 100. He bets 50 or raises 50 but this is a huge re-raise.

Did he flop it or is he taking control of my tight-passive image?

Comment: I think that the 4-bet is actually a 3-bet... the raise from 15 to 45 is a just a raise... the re-raise to 145 is actually the 3-bet. Please check.

Comment: @sobolan is right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you think you have the best hand then going all-in is about the only move that's left as a sensible option.

That said, for us to be ahead, villain would have to have J7x, J8x, 87x (Two pairs); J9x, T8x, T9x, T7x (Pair+Gutshots); 96x, 65x (Open Ended Straight Draws); AJx (TPTK, although I doubt he'd be this aggressive?!).

Otherwise, we're behind JJ, 88, T9x.

If you perceive the villain to be loose and still very aggressive, then I'd move AI, with the assumption that he's playing a high percentage of the hands we beat this way. If he's slightly tighter now, as you say, then I think it's a much closer decision. Either way, the villain is repping that he has decent equity.

Personally, as it is, it seem like a *fold*. If you're behind, which I think is very likely, then you have few redraws as they're compromised by his better sets.

Comment: I agree with you. I went `AllIn`. He `snap-called` me. Knew I was behind but had `outs`! He had the `straight`! The turn was Kx and river was Kx!! My first `suckout` win for a 900+ pot. Having played with the villain for the past 3 hours, he won  4 pots against me with aggressive betting but I wanted to take chances here and it worked, though it was a wrong decision. I did not put him on a set. Put him on a `straight` or a `QT` and felt like he was drawing to a `straight `.

Comment: Months earlier, I have had a suckout loss when I had a straight on the flop and turn gave a 4 card straight on the board but still my (another) opponent called his top Kings set to my all in and the river paired the board. I actually thought about this hand before I went allin above.

Comment: You can definitely count out JJ/88 because of his initial limp. T9x fits pretty well with a limp/call and then a 3-bet after the flop. He didn't display much strength on the flop and then reps the nuts. He's probably got it. Definitely a tough fold though against a LAG player like that, though.

Comment: nice read, Chris.

Comment: I think this would be an absolutely horrible fold. You'll often be up against a hand you have dominated, two pairs or overpairs (overpairs are perfectly reasonable here - he limp-raised you preflop). And when he does have a flopped set or straight, you still have outs to the full house. This would be a tremendously bad fold. It's a wet board. Protect your set and move all-in.

Comment: @Chris - no, you can't rule out 88+. Live players will often limp big pairs to slowplay and trap, QQ+ for instance. And they also frequently either massively oversize a preflop raise with JJ-88, because they have a pair that is hard to play postflop, or will limp it for the same reason. I would never, ever be folding this against a LAG player.

Answer (score 4):

First of all this is not a huge raise. I'm assuming the SB didn't contribute money postflop.
I wouldn't be too worried about a higher set because it's too unlikely to really worry about it, but it is obviously part of his range.
The read said that he was a hyper-aggressive player, and without other information we have to include bluffs in his range here.
We are facing a $100 bet with 30+45+145=220 in the pot. I don't really think we can fold with these odds, so the options are calling or raising with the only reasonable raise size being all in. If we call he will obviously go all in with all the hands that aren't bluffs and with some hands that are. So the implied odds give us the call here, although we might have to fold to a shove on the turn since we can be fairly sure that we're behind with 10 outs at that point.
I think a shove is the only reasonable option here. I really don't think this is a fold against a lot of people especially at 1/2 live.

Comment: Yes, I shoved basically because of the scenario on turn - what if he shoves. I wanted to play till the river and I risked. It is one of those hands (under 500) and you still have 23% on river to pair the board, better odds than shooting craps. If both our stacks were over 550, then it would have been a tough decision between call/fold considering a shove possibility on turn.

Answer (score 2):

Once the SB chooses not to cbet you should certainly be leading here OTF. You're giving him a chance to draw out on you with way too many pair+gutshot hands and this board is fairly coordinated so you should be getting at least one call reasonably often.

Once you check the flop, it's pretty close between calling or raising, but I think raising is slightly better. Either way, I think betting flop in the first place is way better than either of those options.

Once he 3bets we're pretty much screwed and I doubt we can call profitably, so fold. This is just another argument for why the c/r is meh in the first place. Also note that we can definitely bet/call this flop, but can't check/raise/call due to stack sizes.

Comment: At 1/2, chances for drawing out occurs all the time. It is because if I bet more, they fold and I scoop a low pot or I if bet low, they will call and I get trapped. So it is always how much you can afford to gamble.  I checked because I knew he was going to bet regardless. His 3bet there was a huge bet and I should have folded or just called to check/call on turn until the board pairs but I was in the mood to gamble because it is my 1st buy in and ~450 is allright for me to gamble 23% at river for board to pair. If I had more than 550, I would have thought otherwise.

Comment: Just because they call doesn't mean that "you get trapped." In fact, you want them to call because your bet is clearly a value bet (many hands that are hopelessly behind yours will call, and even the ones that are drawing will still call). 

If you are confident that villain will bet then a c/r is fine - but you better be happy getting it in versus a 3bet in that scenario or you are lighting money on fire.